# How can I make my webpage responsive when I minimize the page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hi I have page where I am placing **image** on left side of page and **description** on right side of page. I have **terms** content which I am placing below image and description contents. Now when i minimize, I can see only part of the description contents which fits screen. But how i want is when i minimize, description should drop below images and terms should drop below description.

This is my class for image which I am placing on left side of body :

```
  .appPreview {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  margin-left : 55px;
  }
 span.grey {
 color: #cecece;
  }
```

This is my class for placing description on right side of body :

```
 .right_content
    {
        float: left;

        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        width: 400px;
        margin-top : -520px;
      padding-bottom : 150px;
    }
```

This is my class for placing terms below Image and description :

```
div.MoreInfoterms {
width : 850px;
margin-right : 250px;
margin-left : 55px;
margin-top : 20px;
border: 1px solid #cecece;
background-color: #f7f9f9;
max-height:700px; 
margin-bottom : 20px;
}
```

I really don't know how to achieve this So any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should look into media queries.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
   .appPreview {
      display: block;
   }
   .right_content {
      float: none;
   }
   div.MoreInfoterms {
      width: 100%;
   } 
}
```

You should use percentage instead of px.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up as many as you want by simply creating min/max size boundaries.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/small.css" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width:800px)">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/medium.css" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:801px) and (max-width:1000px)">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/large.css" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:1001px)">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a responsive webpage, you need to use media queries, you can see some standard ones here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

they basically change when the css put in it is applied.

Comment: the answer of Daniel here would work, but it is unwanted since you need more different files which is not handy to work with, and will make your webpage take longer to load.

Answer (score 0):

It's advisable to start with your mobile styles first, then add your additional styles for larger devices as media queries using `min-width`. I find this approach makes things much easier to plan and maintain. Look at [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/) for an in-depth tutorial.